# continuous movement animation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

[continuous movement](http://templates.joomlart.com/ja_events/)

I would like to recreate the truck moments in the above site , It is done in mootools. How would I code this, is there a jQuery plugin to do this?

So animate an object from beginning to end of screen and then it starts over again. How would I do this jQuery

Any help will e appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle sample http://www.jsfiddle.net/XpAjZ/

More on jQuery animate: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Demonstration shows 2 boxes animated across the screen at different speeds etc.  (See fiddle)

Relevant jQuery Code:

```
var animateMe = function(targetElement, speed){

    $(targetElement).css({left:'-200px'});
    $(targetElement).animate(
        {
        'left': $(document).width() + 200
        },
        {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function(){
            animateMe(this, speed);
            }
        }
    );

};
animateMe($('#object1'), 5000);
animateMe($('#object2'), 3000);
```

Comment: Hi how would i go about adding a stop/start on hover, so i hover over it it stops moving i mouseout again and it continues, I see the stop() but dont see a start() or continue

Comment: here's an additional demo on that (it's exactly the same other than checking for position (in case we want to animate) and binding some "container" to hover:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/XpAjZ/1/  Sorry I couldn't answer sooner, was called away.

Comment: hi thanks but I menat hover on the objects so the animate but if i hover over one of them that one stops, i have been playing with that one but i dont get the correct results yet

Comment: well i managed to do what i want but im sure it can be done simpler/cleaner than http://jsfiddle.net/nokiko/btC59/30/

Answer (score 2):

**[Here's an example of the following code.](http://jsfiddle.net/PPVda/)**

This is relatively simple with jQuery using the `position:absolute` CSS property and the `.animation()`<sup>[[DOCS]](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)</sup> method callback.  You will basically be animating the `left` CSS property over a period of time within a named function, then call that function in the animation callback when the animation is complete, like so:

```
var animateTruck = function () {

    $('#truck').css('left','-50px')
               .animate({'left':$(window).width()},
                        4000,
                        'linear',
                        function(){
                            animateTruck();
                        });
};

animateTruck();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div with a picture inside, like this:

```
<div style="width: 1000px">
<img src="truck.png" id="truck" style="margin-left: -100px" />
</div>
```

Here is an jQuery example to slide the picture over the div/screen:

```
function moveTruck(){
    $('#truck').animate(
        {'margin-left': '1000px'}, 
        3000, // Animation-duration
        function(){
            $('#truck').css('margin-left','-100px');
            moveTruck();
        });
    }

moveTruck();
```

Hope that works out...

Answer (score 0):

How could you do this, yet have the content box slowly move back and forth across the width of the screen (not going through the screen and starting back at the other side)?

Comment: I know you made this an answer because you don't have the reputation yet to post comments, but just so you know for the future, this is better served as a comment on a question than an answer, since it doesn't answer the question. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Sorry about that, yes I'm new here.  I just clicked the Add Comment button and didn't realized it was an answer. Yet, actually, I did have a question about the last answer.