# how can we display text letter by letter using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

```js
  var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) 
  {    
    if (index < message.length) 
    { 
      $(target).append(message[index++]); 
      setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval); 
    } 
  }
  $(function () 
  { 
    showText(".animate", "College Search Simplified", 0, 100);    
  });
```

```html
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="animate"></div>
```

In this code text animated only one time i.e. letter by letter. So, how can I repeat letter of this text continuously using jquery.

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/68e2xbm9/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822524/continuous-movement-animation-with-jquery

Comment: .animate() has a callback function, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13367141/715105

Comment: @Jeff Just a note on StackOverflow...it's generally good practice to accept answers. It helps other users find solutions to similar questions, as well as rewarding those who take the time to help the OP ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [continuous movement animation with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822524/continuous-movement-animation-with-jquery)

Comment: you can simply reset the `index` when all letters are shown, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/knvy9mcr/

Comment: Check the demo section in the link: https://pandeyz.github.io/typewriter-effect/

Answer (score 2):

```js
var showText = function(target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      showText(target, message, index, interval);
    }, interval);
  } else {
    index = 0;
    $(target).html('');
    showText(target, message, index, interval);
  }
}
$(function() {
  showText(".animate", "College Search Simplified", 0, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="animate"></div>
```

working fiddle above

Comment: can u create a fiddle

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, sorry, don't know how to do that(I tried but failed this time but will try in some time again until get success). tested this code at my machine and working fine